# How to convert classifier scores into class labels?

Tags: python, algorithm, class, label, classification

I have a classifier which produce scores between 0 and 1, when a sample is given to the system. When the score is high, the probability of the sample belonging to that classifier is high. I have output of the scores that are generated for each sample calculated by the classifier. The format of the dataset that I have for a classifier can be seen below:

```
Classifier1
S1 0.9
S2 0.84
S3 0.54
...
SN 0.01
```

where Si indicates a sample. I need to find a way to convert these scores into 3 discrete class labels as High Middle and Low according to score values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I will write the code in Python.

Comment: So you should have add a Python tag

Comment: Actually, what I am looking for is not specific to a programming language. What I am looking is an algorithm which converts rankers'(probabilistic classifiers) scores into ordinal classes.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? What do you consider to be high, medium and low?

Comment: Yes, I have written. I have trained a classifier and run the classifier for test data. I have the scores generated by the classifier for test data. I sorted samples in descending order by scores and calculated True Positives, False Positives, False Negatives and True Negatives for different cut-off points. I need to find optimal cutoff points according to scores to convert scores into High, Medium and  Low values. i.e. I want to say if the score is greater than .80 then, classify the sample as "High".